# dsn less connection using text driver

Tags: c++, odbc

I am trying to do ODBC import with DSN-Less connection(using text driver). Is there any way to tell SQLDriverConnect to set COLNAMEHEADER=yes/no? OR I need to use schema.ini to do it?
Actually i don't want to create schema.ini manually, Can I use  SQLConfigDataSource  for dsn less connection? I haven't found any docs regarding this.

Thanks in advance,
Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the schema.ini programatically before you open the text file via SQLDriverConnect. I don't see how SQLConfigDataSources can help you here, as it is specifically intended for manipulating DSNs and you don't have one.

Comment: So there is no way to give this option with out schema.ini? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms715389(VS.85).aspx 
Why can't I specify COLNAMEHEADER in SQLDriverConnect?

Comment: Because SQLDriverConnect parameters describe the connection, not the data.